# javascript get value of control in list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an un-ordered list with items that are generated programatically in web2py...

I'm displaying them in HTML as displayed below... I want to have a textbox that allows a user to type in a string. this string should "toggle" the visibility of the `<li>` values if they match or not.

```
<input type="text" id="userTextSearch" onkeyup="listSearch(this.value)"></input>
<ul id="fileResultsID">
        {{for item in mylist:}} 
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox"  name="FileListItem" id="value"> {{=item}}</label>
            </li>
        {{pass}}
</ul>

function listSearch(textValue)
    {
        var fileGroup = document.getElementById('fileResultsID');
        var items = fileGroup.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var chkBx;

        for(var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++)
        {
            chkBx = items[i].getElementsByTagName('input');


            alert(chkBx.InnerHtml);
            //if(!items[i].value.startswith(textValue))
            //{
            //  items[i].toggle();
            //}

        }

    }
```

So far when I type, nothing visible occurs...

Q: How can get certain `<li>` row items to disappear as the user types?

I will need them all to comeback if the text box is empty too btw

Comment: So as a user types "zy" if there is `<li>crazy</li>, will that `<li>` disappears or is it supposed to be a match with words??

Comment: I would like to perform a "startswith()"... if the user typed "cr" I would only want words that begin with the prefix to appear

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me... I also have a quick loop to renable all of the list items if the textbox is cleared out.

```
function listSearch(textValue){
        var fileGroup = document.getElementById('fileResultsID');
        var items = fileGroup.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var chkBx;

        //check to see if user deleted everything first
        if(!textValue)
        {
            for(var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++)
            {
                items[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        for(var i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; i++)
        {
            chkBx = items[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
            var str = chkBx[0].id

            if(!str.toLowerCase().startsWith(textValue.toLowerCase()))
            {
                items[i].style.display = "none";
            }

        }}
```